# Yii2 Select2 doesn't clear selected value after select2.empty()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

```
$('#category-id').empty();
for (i = 0; i < response[0].category.length; i++) {
    $('#category-id').append($('<option></option>') //here typo mistake
      .attr('value', response[0].category[i].id)
      .attr('selected', 'selected')
      .text(response[0].category[i].category_name));
}
```

This is from javascript code **_form.php** in Transaction View. It is triggered by radiobutton click. Select2 contains income and expense categories. When I selected one income category and clicked expense radio button. The option changed expense categories. But the selected income category still showed. It didn't clear.

```
<?=
$form->field($model, 'category_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => Category::getCategoryListByType($model->transaction_type),
    'options' => [
        'id'  => 'category-id',
        'placeholder' => Yii::t('frontend/common', 'Please select one'),
        'allowClear' => true,
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true]
]);
?>
```

Select2 php code.
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: To clear selection use `$("#category-id").select2("val", "");`

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. It doesn't work. It works with simple select. When I tried with select2, there are some bugs.

Comment: ID can be problematic, try this: `$("#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'category_id').'").select2("val", "");`

Comment: Thanks. your first suggestion is right. The trick is select2("val","") and .empty(). I got it wrong because I called empty() first.

Answer (score 2):

This is worked for me-

`$('#accessories').val('').trigger("change");`

'#accessories' is the id of select2